# C++ I cant upload file to FTP server

Tags: c++, file-upload, ftp

I want to upload a file to my FTP server using C++ code and I'm able to FTP my server with FileZilla.

When I run my C++ code, it throws me an output "3" error ( GetLastError() function returned this value to the FtpPutFile() function

```
#pragma comment (lib,"wininet.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h> //for uploadFile function
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    HINTERNET hint, hftp;
    hint = InternetOpen("FTP", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    hftp = InternetConnect(hint, "MY IP ADRESS", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "MY NAME", "MY PASS", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

    if (!FtpPutFile(hftp, "C://Users//Elliot//Desktop//log.txt", "//log.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
    {
        cout << "FAIL !" << endl;
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "file sended !";
    };
    InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    InternetCloseHandle(hint);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

things i have tried :

- Changing server ( i made new server but still same result )
- Controlling firewall
- Running as adminstrator
- break points ( the ftpputfile is giving the error )

Comment: `C://Users//Elliot//Desktop//log.txt` is an odd way to specify a filename under windows, I would have expected `C:\\Users\\Elliot\\Desktop\\log.txt`

Comment: From the horse's mouth: [ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I changed to  " \\ " still doesnt work... what can i do else ?

Comment: Not sure which path so offends it, the local file path or the remote path or ... fud. I think I see it. You don't need to escape the forward slashes. Give "/log.txt" a try.

Comment: this time it returned " 2 " error code [ ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ]

Comment: Drop the `/` on the remote filename: `FtpPutFile(hftp, "C:\\Users\\Elliot\\Desktop\\log.txt", "log.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0)`. `FtpPutFile()` uploads the file to the remote server's current working directory, so if you want to upload to a specific folder then call `FtpSetCurrentDirectory()` first.

Comment: still didint worked... this time it returend " 3 "  [ ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. File is not there, there is nothing to send. You can easily check the file's path using `std::ifstream` before continuing with internet functions.

Use `FtpSetCurrentDirectory` to set a target directory. In this example I used `"public_html"`, maybe your server is different.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#pragma comment (lib,"wininet.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string file = "C:\\path.txt";
    string site = "www.site.com";
    string user = "username";
    string pass = "password";

    if (!ifstream(file))
    {
        cout << "no file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    HINTERNET hint = InternetOpen(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, 0);
    HINTERNET hftp = InternetConnect(hint, site.c_str(), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,
        user.c_str(), pass.c_str(), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

    if (FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hftp, "public_html"))
    {
        if (!FtpPutFile(hftp, file.c_str(), "log.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0))
        {
            cout << "FAIL!" << endl;
            cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "file sended !";
        }
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
    InternetCloseHandle(hint);
    return 0;
}
```